# How to create Titanium Android Module with external library(jar)?

Tags: android, jar, titanium-mobile, titanium-modules

I am creating the module for the first time in Android. This is one external library which is successfully deployed on native code . Now i want to create one module of that external library the Build has Successfully deployed with AntBuild but How can i open the Intent in Titanium . I have tried by creating the below given function...

```
public void scan(String path) {
     final Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Second.class);
       intent.putExtra(PdfViewerActivity.EXTRA_PDFFILENAME, path);
       getActivity().startActivity(intent); 
}
```

Will this work in Titanium ? or do I have to change something? Or I am in totally wrong direction? If any one could help me it would be great. I really need this.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this links:

1) https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Creating+a+New+Titanium+Module

2) http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Android_Module_Development_Guide